# How to Fill Table Data based on Condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My Tables are defined like below:

`UserData (ColA, ColB, ColC)` - This table fills by .CSV file.

These column names are not fixed and number of Table Columns varies in different .CSV files depending on the customer giving the .CSV file.

```
UserDataDSU (ColD, ColE, ColF, ColG, ColH, ColI, ColJ)
```

Now, I have to fill `UserDataDSU` table with `UserData` table data like below.

If `UserData(ColC)` exists and it has data, then fill `UserDataDSU(ColD)` else set `ColD` as `NULL`

If `UserData(ColA)` exists and it has data, then fill `UserDataDSU(ColE)` else set `ColE` as `NULL`

If `UserData(ColB)` exists and it has data, then fill `UserDataDSU(ColF)` else set `ColF` as `NULL`

Of course, for all the remaining columns in `UserDataDSU` (like `ColG`, `ColH`, `ColI`, `ColJ` does not have data in its couter table - `UserData`, all those should be filled by `NULLs`.

Please remember that for some other .CSV file got from another customer DATA MAY EXISTS FOR SOME OR ALL OF THESE COLUMNS

Can anyone please suggest how to do this inside a Stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**

You can use `sys.objects` to generate a match the columns between tables based on your business logic and then use this mapping to create a dynamic `INSERT` sql script.

Below is the SQL script for all this

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) -- will be used for holding dynamic SQL script
-- this temp table will hold the mapping
CREATE TABLE #temp (DColName varchar(100), SColName varchar(100), OrderCol int) 
--inserting mapping into temp table based on business logic
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT 
    Dest.name, 
    Source.name, 
    Dest.object_id -- ordering criteria to generate accurate mapping in script
FROM 
    sys.columns Dest LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT 
        name,
        CASE 
            WHEN name='ColC' THEN 'ColD' 
            WHEN name='ColA' THEN 'ColE' 
            WHEN name='ColB' THEN 'ColF' 
            ELSE name
        END as Newname -- business logic for matching
    FROM 
        sys.columns 
        WHERE
        object_id IN (
            SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables WHERE name ='UserData'
                    ) 
    )source 
    ON Dest.Name=Source.NewName
    WHERE 
        Dest.object_id IN (
                            SELECT object_id 
                            FROM sys.tables 
                            WHERE name ='UserDataDSU'
                          ) 

--create the dynamic SQL

SELECT @sql =
'INSERT INTO UserDataDSU ('+
--insert column list of destination table  
STUFF((SELECT  ','+ Dcolname FROM #temp WHERE Scolname IS NOT NULL ORDER BY OrderCol ASC FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') +
') SELECT '+
--insert column list of source table
STUFF((SELECT  ','+ Scolname FROM #temp ORDER BY OrderCol ASC FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') +
' FROM UserData' 

-- execute the dynamic SQL
EXEC(@sql)

-- now drop the temp table
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Please note that I tested this and this worked for me.
`CREATE INSERT` table scripts used are below

```
create table UserData (ColA varchar(100), ColB varchar(100), ColC varchar(100));
insert into UserData values ('A1','B1','C1'),('A2','B2','C2');
create table UserDataDSU (ColD varchar(100), ColE varchar(100), ColF varchar(100), ColG varchar(100), ColH varchar(100), ColI varchar(100), ColJ varchar(100));
```